# Linear Algebra - Getting Orthogonal Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not clear on how to construct an orthogonal matrix given an orthogonal set. In this set for example:

$$\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\}$$

I know that the matrix must be orthogonal between both all columns and all rows. Any suggestions on how to manipulate the orthogonal vectors so that they also become perpendicular from row to row in their matrix?

Comment: If you have a collection of $n$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ (the dot product of any two different vectors is zero and the dot product of any vector with itself is 1), the matrix with those vectors as its columns (or its rows) will be orthogonal.  If you have a basis that is orthogonal but not orthonormal, you can get an orthonormal basis by dividing each vector by its length.

Comment: Just normalize the vectors and take them as columns of the matrix!

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

As [Aaron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752323/linear-algebra-getting-orthogonal-matrix#comment3575945_1752323) has already pointed out in the comments, if you have a set of orthogonal vectors, then a matrix with those vectors normalised as its columns will be orthogonal. (You could just as well make the matrix using those rows since the matrix is orthogonal).

So your matrix is:

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Yeah so that was my original problem, by just putting those columns directly into a matrix you only have orthogonal columns but not rows, but like Aaron said you just have to normalize it.

Comment: @Orionm I somehow forgot to normalise itmyself, will edit my post to reflect this.